# How to configure prettier in a browser to properly indent html

Tags: javascript, html, formatting, prettier

I want to format html just by indention. So I've found out that I can do that [using prettier](https://prettier.io/docs/en/browser.html). Here is my current options:

```
import prettier from 'prettier/standalone';
import htmlParser from 'prettier/parser-html';

    return prettier.format(source, {
                    parser: 'html',
                    plugins: [htmlParser],
                    tabWidth: 2,
                    htmlWhitespaceSensitivity: "strict",
                    bracketSpacing: false,
                });
```

What I see is that most of the tags are broken and some didn't start from the new line:

```
<li><p style="margin:0" 
              >123321<a
                href="https://123"
                >123</a
              > 
              (<a href="https://abc">abc</a
              >)</p
            ></li 
          > 
          <li
            ><p style="margin:0"
              ><a
                href="https://xyz"
                >xyz</a
              ></p
            ></li
          >
```

What I want is

```
<li>
    <p style="margin:0">123321
        <a href="https://123">123</a>
    </p>
</li>
<li>
    <p style="margin:0">
        <a href="https://xyz">xyz</a>
    </p>
</li>
```

Any ideas what prettier options would help to achieve that?

Comment: I suspect it's formatting like that because spacing has a certain meaning in html. Prettier knows not to add spacing where it might be meaningful. Don't know if there's an option to turn that off, though. You might get an answer by asking on their [issue tracker](https://github.com/prettier/prettier/issues).

Comment: What are you inputting to prettier, a string a html block? I suspect your input data does contain errors

Answer (score 3):

You can set htmlWhitespaceSensitivity to "ignore" in your options. See https://prettier.io/docs/en/options.html#html-whitespace-sensitivity.

```
return prettier.format(source, { 
        parser: 'html', 
        plugins: [htmlParser], 
        tabWidth: 2, 
        htmlWhitespaceSensitivity: "ignore"
    });
```

The output doesn't look exactly like you wanted it, but closer.

```
<li>
  <p style="margin: 0">
    123321
    <a href="https://123">123</a>
    (
    <a href="https://abc">abc</a>
    )
  </p>
</li>
<li>
  <p style="margin: 0"><a href="https://xyz">xyz</a></p>
</li>
```

Comment: Please add your input, maybe I can see an issue there.